# How to convert an mp4 to mp4 using FFmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I have a set of MP4 files; all of them play with VLC on my Ubuntu box. But when copy them to USB; and want to play them from my TV (Grundig, 28 VLE 5500WG) some work; others do not.There is no specific error message; just something like “unknown file format.”

Mediainfo (working file):

```
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 368 MiB
Duration                                 : 1h 6mn
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 770 Kbps

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 5 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 1h 6mn
Bit rate                                 : 640 Kbps
Width                                    : 720 pixels
Height                                   : 404 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.088
Stream size                              : 306 MiB (83%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 142 r2479 dd79a61
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=5 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=umh / subme=8 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=12 / lookahead_threads=2 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=2 / b_bias=0 / direct=3 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=50 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=19.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 1h 6mn
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 124 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 140 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 59.3 MiB (16%)
```

Mediainfo broken file:

```
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 269 MiB
Duration                                 : 47mn 22s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 793 Kbps
Writing application                      : Stupid Ocelot

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 5 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 47mn 22s
Bit rate                                 : 680 Kbps
Width                                    : 720 pixels
Height                                   : 404 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.094
Stream size                              : 231 MiB (86%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 142 r2479 dd79a61
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=5 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=umh / subme=8 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=12 / lookahead_threads=2 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=2 / b_bias=0 / direct=3 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=50 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=20.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Language                                 : English
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 47mn 22s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 96.0 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 110 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 32.5 MiB (12%)
```

Comment: Given the info you provided I see no practical difference between these files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured one way that works (not sure if it is optimal). Running

```
ffmpeg -i broken.mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 18 good.mp4
```

Creates an MP4 that is a bit larger (probably minimally worse in terms of quality) ... and that works on my TV set.

(but I am still looking for other answers, if there are any)

Comment: Does it also work if you simply remux? `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy output.mp4`.

Comment: I tried; and not, that doesn't work. I guess my TV set like whatever the "Stupid Ocelot" encoder is creating.

Comment: Your solution worked for my case too (an Android screen recording, with cyclothymia framerate). I solved it as well by just doing: `ffmpeg -i broken.mp4 fixed.mp4`, but I guess it's re-encoding, with default settings.

Comment: Your solution helped me.  I recorded the screen and could play with ffplay and chrome but not with firefox or vlc.  This command fixed that.  The record command was
ffmpeg -video_size 1024x768 -framerate 25 -f x11grab -i :0.0+0,0 -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -acodec aac output.mp4

Comment: Thanks @joshua your command helped me. My `BASH_HISTORY` seems to have lost the exact command now but to fix the audio that was not playing on some platforms I did this: `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -acodec aac out.mp4`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following options:

`-c:v libx264 -crf 24 -pix_fmt yuv420p -tune film -c:a aac -b:a 192k -ar 44100 -vol 300 -strict -2 -speed fastest`

The final result should run smoothly on most TVs.

Comment: This code in shall run video smoothly in any tv

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts. Please note: just repeating your claim as comment isn't really helpful. You already said so. Beyond that, remember that your content might sit here for a long time, and many people might look at it. Thus: take a bit more time, to write down something that is really helpful. It starts with proper formatting (maybe learn about the markdown language *you* can **use** here to `mark` stuff). And more importantly: dont just drop "code" on your readers. Take the time to *explain* what your options do, and why you think your idea is "better" than the other answer!